# How to use SAS macro with %DO and %IF

Tags: sas, sas-macro

When I ran a macro, the `PassengerID_Class` had a null value.

I think there is a problem with the sentence below.

`%if PassengerID >= &&P&i and PassengerID < &&P&k %then PassengerID_Class = &i. ;`

`PassengerID` is a column containing values from `1` to `891`.

`P1`,`P2`,...,`Pi` are the quantiles.

Below is my code.

```
%macro do_loop;

DATA _NULL_;
SET PERCENTILES100_Transpose;
call symput("P"||left(_n_),Column1);
RUN;  

Data Groups100;
Set sample;

%do i=2 %to 99;
%Let k = %eval(&i.+1);
%if PassengerID >= &&P&i and PassengerID < &&P&k %then PassengerID_Class = &i. ;
%end;

%mend;

%do_loop;
```

Comment: Why are you using a macro `%IF` if you want to test the value of an actual variable?  Use an IF statement for that.

Comment: And if you want to split data into quantiles, PROC RANK will do that in a single PROC. `proc rank data=sashelp.class out=ranks groups=2; var weight; ranks weight_rank; run;`. No need for multiple steps, merging, etc.

Comment: Change groups=10 for deciles.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test the value of dataset variable with a macro expression.  Just use the macro to generate a normal IF statement, the same as you are using the macro to generate the DATA and other SAS statements.

```
if &&P&i <= PassengerID < &&P&k then PassengerID_Class = &i. ;
```

But why use macro code at all?  Just read the cutoff values into a temporary array.

```
data Groups100;
  set sample;
  array p[100] _temporary_;
  if _n_=1 then do index=1 by 1 until(eof);
     set PERCENTILES100_Transpose(keep=column1) end=eof;
     p[index]=column1;
  end;
  PassengerID_Class=0;
  do index=2 to 99 until(PassengerID_Class>0);
    if p[index] <= PassengerID < p[index+1] then PassengerID_Class = index ;
  end;
  drop index column1 ;
run;
```

Note that using the data directly will also avoid loss of precision caused by converting the numbers into text strings to store macro variables.

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved the problem. It really helped a lot. Thank you.